# Mysql Process Progress

Tags: mysql

I need to run a procedure which will handle long running queries for about 200 branches.
Is there anyway to notify the client after the completion of each branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably need some server-side management of long queries, and the at the client side (I suppose, it's a browser?) you'll need to poll periodically some service URL which would send current status to the client.

It's hardly possible you could run your long query manager in regular request-based php thread. Google for PHP (or your language of choice) queue manager.

Also, you may use websockets to push updates to client, without needing of active polling from his side. But, AFAIK, this technology is relatively new and not too widely supported yet